# what is the purpose of req.body in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

why req.body is called in the code

```js
post(function(req, res, next) {
  res.end('Will add the promotion: ' + req.body.name + ' with details: ' + req.body.description);
})
```

Comment: It contains the body of the request. Express provides body parsers. If the body is JSON data it's parsed and you can access the elements, e.g. `req.body.name` and `req.body.description`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics](https://www.google.com/search?q=node+what+is+req+body)<<<***

Comment: If you have a question, you should comment, please do not post.

Answer (score 1):

## `req`

The `req` object contains the *request*, that is, the thing the *client* sends to your server.

Let's look at a common HTTP request scenario:

```
POST /gimme-json HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: some cool user agent
Content-Type: application/json

{ "hello": "world" }
```

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

{"ok":true}
```

Now, let's see how we would implement this in Express:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

// this will take the JSON bodies and put it into 'req.body'
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/gimme-json', (req, res) => {
    console.log('req.body =', req.body); // logs "req.body = { "hello": "world" }"
    res.json({ ok: true });
});

app.listen(80, () => {});
```

See? `req.body` contains the *body* of the request as parsed by whatever middleware you have.

In this case, the middleware stack is simple:

```
           HTTP GET
      | express internals |
      |JSON parser to body|
      |  handler for GET  |
```